# Why do I get a text that reads "feet" on the top corner of the 3d viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

[image: I somehow now have this in my startup file.].

I somehow now have this in my startup file. Can someone tell me what this represents and how to change/remove it?

Answer (score 10):

*That are your units of measurement.*

For Version 2.8X Enable/Disable **Text Info** in the **Overlay** Controls.

[image]

Then set the scale to the **Unit System** in which you measure.

[image]

For Versions 2.7x

You can change them under the Unit tab in the Scene Properties menu.

[image]

If you want "Blender" measurements just set the length to none.

Comment: Doh! Of course it is. I was confused because one of my last projects was to model a chair of mine and I had renamed the mesh of the feet, well, "feet". I thought somehow that was related. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That is the unit you're using in your current project, it is set from the scene tab (see image below), to set it to how it is by default you have to select Meters in the tab where it says Miles and then set the length to None. 
Basically, you chose Feet as the default lenght to work with so every square in the blender grid is 1 feet long to you. In the Scene tab you see below you can choose which unit to use when you work which can be pretty useful if you want to do things precisely.

[image]